# How to plot Transform.Forward over time

Tags: matlab, unity-game-engine, graph, 3d

I'm trying to use Matlab to visualize the following Transform data sample from a Unity simulation. What I'm most interested in is the direction the game object was facing. At time `t`, `x, y, z` are the transform's position and `fx, fy, fz` is [Transform.Forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html).

```
t   x  y   z  fx   fy   fz
1   29 1.7 53 -0.3 -0.6 -0.8
2   29 1.7 54 -0.2 -0.5 -0.9
3   29 1.7 55 -0.1 -0.4 -0.9
4   29 1.7 56 -0.1 -0.3 -0.9
5   29 1.7 57 -0.1 -0.2 -1
```

Assuming this is enough info, how could I visualize which directions were faced over time? What kind of graph would be able to capture time and facing direction in this form? Is it doable with something like a [histogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html)

Comment: Not sure if you need it for analytics. Maybe you want to have a [heat map](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/analytics/unity-analytics-heatmaps-65801)? Unity HeatMap is a bit outdated, but if you are already tracking data you might represent them with your tools.

Comment: @JackMariani I'm actually looking for a solution outside of Unity. I'll update the question to reflect that. I'll look into heat maps in general though.

Comment: Your question should be of the form "I have [data], and this is how I want to plot it [image]. How do I do this in MATLAB?". Instead you seem to be asking "I have [data]. Can I get some suggestions on how to visualize it?" - this makes it an opinion-based question, which is not good for SO. I would suggest showing some several time steps of this matrix, and show a similar plot to what you want to get.